# Wine not running on Google Cloud Run (limitations of google cloud run)

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run, wine

This is my docker file, which is installing wine in order to run some exes that I want to, on Google cloud run:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE="ubuntu"
ARG TAG="latest"
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}:${TAG}

# Install prerequisites
RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        apt-transport-https \
        ca-certificates \
        cabextract \
        git \
        gosu \
        gpg-agent \
        p7zip \
        pulseaudio-utils \
        software-properties-common \
        tzdata \
        unzip \
        wget \
        winbind \
        xvfb \
        zenity \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install wine
ARG WINE_BRANCH="stable"
RUN wget -O- -nv https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | apt-key add - \
    && apt-add-repository "deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ $(grep VERSION_CODENAME= /etc/os-release | cut -d= -f2) main" \
    && dpkg --add-architecture i386 \
    && apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install -y --install-recommends winehq-${WINE_BRANCH} \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install winetricks
RUN wget -nv https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks -O /usr/bin/winetricks \
    && chmod +x /usr/bin/winetricks

# Download gecko and mono installers
COPY download_gecko_and_mono.sh /root/download_gecko_and_mono.sh
RUN chmod +x /root/download_gecko_and_mono.sh \
    && /root/download_gecko_and_mono.sh "$(dpkg -s wine-${WINE_BRANCH} | grep "^Version:\s" | awk '{print $2}' | sed -E 's/~.*$//')"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3.6 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install flask gunicorn
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod a+x /usr/bin/wine
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn","-w","1","--timeout","900","-b","0.0.0.0:8005","app:app"]
EXPOSE 8005
```

I have tested this container locally on my linux 64 bit machine, and it is able to run the wine commands (app.py is a flask server that calls exes).
But when I try to call "wine" on the GCR container (I even tried calling it at the beginning of my app.py, which is guaranteed to run), I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker worker.init_process() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process self.load_wsgi() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi self.callable = self.load() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load return self.load_wsgiapp() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp return util.import_app(self.app_uri) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app mod = importlib.import_module(module) File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/app/app.py", line 27, in <module> print(subprocess.call(["wine"]) File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 340, in call with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p: File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__ self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename) OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: 'wine'
```

The important line in the error being:

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error:
```

It is particularly odd because I would assume docker would guarantee portability across linux platforms.

## EDIT:

The original issue was that I was not using wine64 (gcr only supports linux 64 bit binaries ), which resolved the original issue of wine running.

However, due to Cloud Run fully managed using gVisor sandbox, it was still not possible to get my exe running.
I have eventually moved to other approaches to solve my problem.

Comment: Do you have GVisor error or warning in your logs before the crash?

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that Wine does not work on Cloud Run fully managed.

Cloud Run fully managed uses gVisor sandbox (https://gvisor.dev/), which is an user-space syscall emulator written in Go. This environment does not run a real Linux kernel or real Docker runtime.

It's expected that there could be compatibility issues with exotic executables such as Wine (that exercise the syscall APIs to their full extent and corner cases). However, most server-side apps should be working fine.

You can [use strace on Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting/tracing-system-calls) to identify the culprit syscall and [make a feature request to gVisor](https://github.com/google/gvisor/issues) mentioning you need this on Cloud Run. Alternatively, you can use Cloud Run for Anthos, which runs on Kubernetes, with a real Linux kernel and Docker (or containerd).

Comment: After going through the logs, yes, I think it is a gvisor issue. it is a bummer that GCR doesnt support wine. is there something similar with the same pricing model?

Comment: Unlikely. However, feel free to file a bug to gVisor with the failing syscall. I imagine Wine is probably one of the most exotic things you can probably run in this environment. Maybe it’s a small fix. Also please accept the answer :)

Comment: I understand that this use was exotic, but me and my employer were sold on the promise of "any language, or operating system libraries, or even bring your own binaries" https://cloud.google.com/run 
we assumed docker with windows was supported, but had to find out it was not (it is mentioned in the runtime contract, but it is NOT simple to find), and there is the gvisor restriction, which is also not mentioned. I think at least an * around that claim is warranted, with links to limitations of the GCR runtime.